# Dynamic add custome view and set it's property android

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I have added [SingleFingerView](https://github.com/ryanch741/android-view-rotate-zoom-single-finger/blob/master/src/com/example/testimg/SingleFingerView.java) which is custom view

it's xml properties are

```
<com.example.testimg.SingleFingerView
        android:id="@+id/tiv"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        pushtouch:centerInParent="true"
        pushtouch:image="@drawable/crown"
        pushtouch:image_height="150dp"
        pushtouch:image_width="200dp"
        pushtouch:push_image="@drawable/push_btn"
        pushtouch:push_image_height="50dp"
        pushtouch:push_image_width="50dp" />
```

But I have add this custom view by Java

```
LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                SingleFingerView btn = new SingleFingerView(MyActivity.this);
                btn.setLayoutParams(lparams);
```

But i don't know how to set it's pushtouch property by java

```
     pushtouch:centerInParent="true"
        pushtouch:image="@drawable/crown"
        pushtouch:image_height="150dp"
        pushtouch:image_width="200dp"
        pushtouch:push_image="@drawable/push_btn"
        pushtouch:push_image_height="50dp"
        pushtouch:push_image_width="50dp"
```

Can anybody help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create public methods for each of your attributes in your SingleFingerView, for example:

```
public void setCenterInParent(boolean centerInParent) {
    this.mCenterInParent = centerInParent;
}

public void setImageDrawable(Drawable d) {
    this.mImageDrawable = d;
}

public void setImageHeight(int height) {
    this.mImageHeight = height * _1dp;
}
```

And then in your activity/fragment:

```
LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
SingleFingerView btn = new SingleFingerView(MyActivity.this);
btn.setLayoutParams(lparams);
btn.setCenterInParent(true);
btn.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.crown));
btn.setImageHeight(200);
```